# Find the position of all leaves in tree (JAVA)

Tags: java, tree

Lets assume that I have a tree as like below:

```
     O
    / \
   O   \
  / \   \
 A   B   C
```

How would I go about finding the position of all the leaves in this tree and output them in an array or HashMap?

So the above tree would return:

```
{{  A   ,     00      },{  B   ,     01      },{  C   ,   1   }}
   leaf    left, left     leaf   left, right     leaf   right
```

I was thinking to iterate down the tree until it found a leaf and remember which path it took. But I am not quite sure whether this is the most efficient way of doing this.

Any ideas how this could be implemented?

Comment: You can iterate down the tree until you find a leaf and remember which path it took. Really this question sounds too much like "I want someone else to do it for me, I will say something and I expect that I get an answer with code"

Comment: Why do you think this is so? Did I ask for code?! I already had the idea of iterating down, I was asking for advice for a more efficient way.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that there's no already existing metadata that can be used, the easiest solution is probably just a regular Depth-First search with a stack containing the path taken so far. I don't see how one could do it in a significantly more efficient way.